# overlapping occupancy grid maps

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to overlap two pose estimation (from the particle filter) with the map asociated to each of them (the map is the same). After that i need to merge both maps.

As a first step I am choose one pose estimation as fixed and I am trying to rotate and translate the otherone to overlap the fixed one (map included). The problem is that I dont know how to rotate and translate de occupancy grid map.

An image with the problem description is attached.
Thanks in advance![image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275147/overlapping-occupancy-grid-maps/) by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finaly could resolve this problem.
The way I did it was

1. Calculate the offset between fixed pose and the other pose
2. Create a frame (with tf2 tools) applying the translation and rotation between the poses
3. Then copy the original map, and set the frame_id with the frame created in 2)

You can see the results in the picture.
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) with karma: 81 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0